# The problem of arranging seats

Tags: probability

If $12$ people, consisting of $4$ families of three, are randomly arranged in a row, find the probability that no family sits together (allowing two members of a family to sit together but not all three).

Here is my thinking to solve this problem.
Let event $E_i = \{\text{the members of family $i$ will sit all together}\}$, then the desired probability will be $1 - P(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3 \cup E_4)$.

Comment: Your idea is correct.  Have you tried to implement it?  If so, please show us what you have attempted.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: (Python says that the probability is about 0.688, but I don't suppose this is very helpful)

Comment: I have tried to solve this by expanding it using the inclusion-exclusion

Comment: But I don't know how to find the probability of $P(Ei \cap Ej) or P(Ei \cap Ej \cap Ek)$

Answer (score 3):

Your thinking of using inclusion-exclusion on $P(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3 \cup E_4)$ is correct. Here is how you can solve for $P(E_i)$, $P(E_i\cap E_j)$ and $P(E_i\cap E_j \cap E_k)$ for $i,j,k\in \{1,2,3,4\}$ distinct.

For $P(E_i)$, we are looking at the situations when family $i$ is sitting together. Since they are all together, and otherwise we have 9 people to arrange, there are $10!$ ways to arrange everyone while keeping the family together and not yet caring how the family is arranging themeselves (in a sense, the family is the 10th "person" that needs to be arranged). Since there are $3!$ ways to arrange the people within the family, we have $3!10!$ total arrangements in $E_i$. As there are $12!$ arrangements in general, we get that $P(E_i)=\frac{3!10!}{12!}=\frac{1}{22}$ for each $i$.

For the other cases, we use similar reasoning in which we first keep each family together, and then multiply to account for how each family is arranged within themselves. This gives us $P(E_i\cap E_j)=\frac{8!3!3!}{12!}=\frac{1}{330}$, $P(E_i\cap E_j \cap E_k)=\frac{6!3!3!3!}{12!}=\frac{1}{3080}$, and $P(E_1\cap E_2 \cap E_3\cap E_4)=\frac{4!3!3!3!3!}{12!}=\frac{1}{15400}$.

Now we can use inclusion-exclusion to solve the problem:
\begin{align}
&1-P(E_1\cup E_2\cup E_3\cup E_4)\\&=1-\sum_{i=1}^4 P(E_i)+\sum_{i,j=1\\i<j}^4 P(E_i\cap E_j) - \sum_{i,j,k=1\\i<j<k}^4 P(E_i\cap E_j \cap E_k)+P(E_1\cap E_2 \cap E_3\cap E_4)\\
&= 1-4(\frac{1}{22})+ {4 \choose 2}\frac{1}{330}- {4\choose 3}\frac{1}{3080}+\frac{1}{15400}\\
&=1-\frac{4}{22}+\frac{6}{330}-\frac{4}{3080}+\frac{1}{15400}\\
&\approx 0.835
\end{align}

Comment: Here is a link to python code that approximates the solution: https://www.online-python.com/7TnpKbz2RF

Comment: Thank you so much, Adam! My answer actually matches with yours. T